# Using kotlin extension function in Java code

Tags: java, android, kotlin, fragment

I have created an extension function for listening to click listener for buttons, when I try to access it from Java code it does not work,

Cannot access clicks() from java file, this is what I tried

Can you please suggest how to resolve this.

Thanks
R

File - Extension.kt

```
   fun Button.clicks(): Flow<Unit> = callbackFlow {
        setOnClickListener {
            offer(Unit)
        }
        awaitClose { setOnClickListener(null) }
    }
```

In my java code - FillingFragment.java

```
 @NotNull
    @Override
    public Flow<Void> getStartFillingObservableFlow() {
        return dataViewHolder.btnStartFilling.clicks(); //CLICKS IS NOT. RECOGNISED
    }
```

DataViewHolder.Java

```
  @BindView(R.id.start_filling_action)
    public Button btnStartFilling;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension functions usually compiles to statics functions so you can invoke them like this:

```java
ExtensionKt.clicks(dataViewHolder.btnStartFilling);
```

Comment: Hello @andei, I tried that and able to access it now

Comment: It gives me an error Required type:
Flow
<Void>
Provided:
Flow
<Unit>

Comment: how can I make the extension function return void?

Comment: or should I be working with Unit instead of void

Comment: I think your `getStartFillingObservableFlow` function should return `Flow<Unit>`